Building apr-util for log4cxx using cmake throws errors
I am trying to build log4cxx (on Windows) library for logging runtime info in my c++ project. As part of the build I have to build also two dependency libraries called apr and apr-util. I have successfully built the apr library, but can't build apr-util. I am using for the build, the tool called cmake.
I am following the build instructions from the Apache page here.
I have browsed the internet to find out if somebody else has been struggling with the same problem as me but found nothing. I know the project is alive because there were some commits last week.
When I am building apr-util the compiler throws plenty of errors like below:
C:\msys64\ucrt64\include\winnt.h(137,1): error C1189: #error:  No supported target architecture. [C:\tools\buildtrees\a
pr-util\libaprutil-1.vcxproj]
C:\tools\apr-util-1.6.3\include\apr_buckets.h(29,10): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'apr_network_io.h': No suc
h file or directory [C:\tools\buildtrees\apr-util\libaprutil-1.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\ucrt64\include\stdlib.h(389,32): error C2085: '_exit': not in formal parameter list [C:\tools\buildtrees\apr-
util\libaprutil-1.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\ucrt64\include\stdlib.h(389,49): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'type' [C:\tools\buildtrees\ap
r-util\libaprutil-1.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\ucrt64\include\stdlib.h(391,32): error C2085: 'quick_exit': not in formal parameter list [C:\tools\buildtrees
\apr-util\libaprutil-1.vcxproj]
  apr_buckets_eos.c
C:\msys64\ucrt64\include\stdlib.h(391,54): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'type' [C:\tools\buildtrees\ap
r-util\libaprutil-1.vcxproj]
C:\msys64\ucrt64\include\stdlib.h(396,16): error C2085: '_Exit': not in formal parameter list [C:\tools\buildtrees\apr-
util\libaprutil-1.vcxproj]


I even started to analyse their building scripts but I don't understand most of it so it is impossible to come to some conclusion in such a short time that I have.
I am using the following versions of the two dependencies:

apr-util-1.6.3
apr-1.7.4

I have browsed internet to find out if somebody else did face the same problem
I have been changing build scripts to experiment with the build logic but they are very difficult to understand.
I have send a message to log4cxx group log4cxx-user-help@logging.apache.org but have not heard from them so far.

My advice is to not build from source instead just use pacman to install this package: https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-log4cxx?repo=ucrt64 The install command is on that page: pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-log4cxx do this from a msys2 terminal.

I might try pacman later but want to figure out what is wrong with following apacche instructions.

#error:  No supported target architecture. seems like a serious problem.

Wait a minute error C1189 You are using msvc? Then my advice changes to follow the build instructions on the site you linked. vcpkg install apr apr-util is the msvc instructions. The msys2 instructions are for MinGW.

@drescherjm Thanks for the reply. Are you saying there is another set of instructions using vcpkg tool or I misunderstood you?

vcpkg is a tool from Microsoft that can be used to build this for you using your msvc compiler. https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
